# C# 4.0 IronPython 2.7.5 PythonGlobal[] holding memory

Tags: c#, ironpython

I've been searching around for a while and come up with nothing (that works). I have an application (external) that calls a new application. This application makes use of the Microsoft ConsoleHost and the IronPython tool for C#. The issue is after we exit the IronPython sessions, all appears to close and collect, but when running Redgate ANTS, there are thousands of instances of PythonAST's and NameExpressions being held in memory. Would this possibly be caused by the entire application Not being shut down? By this i mean we exit the secondary application, leaving the external one open.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago, jdhary had fixed some IronPython memory leaks. Just clone the current repository and try if this solves your problem. Just take a look at: [Fix IronPython memory leaks when creating multiple engines](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/pull/1250)